# C# Add conditional directly inside string

Tags: c#, string

I have a boolean `isEuropean` and based on it's value I want to write

```
Console.WriteLine("This individual is/is not European");
```

Is it possible in C# to add a conditional directly inside a string with no additional variables created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isEuropean = true;
Console.WriteLine($"This individual {(isEuropean ? "is" : "is not")} European");
```

Yes, you can do string interpolation with a ternary, make sure you contain the ternary in parentheses.